# Trying to perform a web scrapping with Python in Forbes opinion articles

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using the following python code, but I only get a CSV with one row 3 columns, the cells only say "Title" "Body" "Date":

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

base_url = "https://forbes.es"

def scrape_forbes_article(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.find("h1", {"class": "article__title"}).text.strip()
    body = soup.find("div", {"class": "article__body"}).text.strip()
    date = soup.find("time", {"class": "article__date"})["datetime"]
    return title, body, date

def get_article_links(page_link):
    page = requests.get(page_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    article_links = [base_url + item["href"] for item in soup.select("h2.card__title a")]
    return article_links

def main():
    articles_data = []

    for i in range(1, 60):
        page_link = f"https://forbes.es/seccion/opinion/page/{i}/"
        article_links = get_article_links(page_link)
        
        for link in article_links:
            title, body, date = scrape_forbes_article(link)
            articles_data.append([title, body, date])

    with open('forbes_opinion_articles.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Title', 'Body', 'Date']
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(fieldnames)
        for article in articles_data:
            writer.writerow(article)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to get three columns with that data. One column that gives all the title of the articles. One with the body of the articles. One with the date of each. I can work with only 2 columns, one for the body and other for the date.

Comment: I would first check that your "articles_data" has actually data. In your "scrape_forbes_article", you could make an "if response.status_code == 200" conditional, because it can be that you are not even getting a positive answer from the Forbes server.

Comment: You are right, the code is not retrieving a positive answer, what can I do?

Comment: What do you get as a response status code (e.g. 404 resource not found)? With this error code and its message (response.text), you will get more info to know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

While debugging your code,
I found that the XPaths and class names are no longer available.

You can replace the following line:

```
article_links = [base_url + item["href"] for item in soup.select("h2.card__title a")]
```

with the revised line below, as item["href"] itself is a complete URL:

```
article_links = [item["href"] for item in soup.select("h2.card__title a")]
```

Additionally, consider adding a try-catch block to capture and identify any exceptions or errors that may occur during the execution of your code. This will assist in troubleshooting and fixing issues.